# How do you deal with being behind on a task?

Tags: agile, scrum, estimation, deadlines, task

I have a question for you guys. Say, you're given a task as an item in a product backlog. Say, you have a deliverable that's due the following day. If you're behind on the task compared to when you made your estimates, what do you do about it? Does it make you anxious knowing your behind schedule? How do you deal with this? Do you tell the scrum master or the product owner?

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, it makes me anxious. But I am usually both behind and anxious anyway.
- That's what daily standups are for -- so the team doesn't discover a week later that you're a week behind.

Answer (score 1):

I would usually relay that information to the scrum master during the daily scrum meeting. As soon as you know you're behind you should inform the scrum master so he can either get someone to help you (maybe someone else is ahead of schedule and has bandwidth to help), determine whether overtime is needed, or if it's an impediment outside of your team's control then the backlog item needs to be deferred he can provide rationale to stakeholders.

Comment: Working overtime should really only be a last resort for if the feature is actually _needed_ at the end of that sprint (say, due to a bad promise from marketing).  Otherwise your velocity is going to get screwed up and create the expectation that this higher number of story points is normal.